# Material UI: StartAdornment is not working with label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, adornment

The standard variant of 'TextField' is not working as expected if 'StartAdornment' is added with an icon.

If I add `StartAdornment` the label remains up. I want the label should work as placeholder and goes up when the focus is in TextField.

Here is the **[SandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-compiler-forked-rl1jhz?file=/src/temp.js)**:

```
export const Temp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid sx={{ mt: 1.5 }}>
        <TextField
          variant="standard"
          required
          fullWidth
          label="Enter Mobile Number"
          autoFocus
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <LoginRoundedIcon
                sx={{ p: 0.25, color: "#A9A9A9", ml: -0.5, mr: 1 }}
                position="start"
              >
                <Visibility></Visibility>
              </LoginRoundedIcon>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [limitation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#shrink) that we can overcome with a work-around like this:

```
const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState("");


<TextField
      variant="standard"
      required
      fullWidth
      label="Enter Mobile Number"
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <LoginRoundedIcon
            sx={{ p: 0.25, color: "#A9A9A9", ml: -0.5, mr: 1 }}
            position="start"
          >
            <Visibility></Visibility>
          </LoginRoundedIcon>
        )
      }}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: focused || currentValue,
        style: { marginLeft: 30 }
      }}
      value={currentValue}
      onChange={(e) => setCurrentValue(e.target.value)}
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-startadornment) for a live working example of this work-around.